Proof verification: in a PID, submodules of a free and finitely generated module are also free and finitely generated

Let $R$ be a PID and $M$ a free, finitely generated $R$-module of rank $n$. Then
every submodule of $M$ is free, finitely generated, and of rank $m \leq n$.

I know there are other proofs for this and similar results, but I am interested in this proof in particular,
My proof is as follows:
Since $M$ is free of rank $n$, we have $M \cong R^n$, so let $S$ be a submodule of $R^n$. Proceed by induction on $n$.
If $n = 1$, then $S$ is a submodule of $R$, i.e an ideal. If $S = 0$ then it is free with basis $\varnothing$ and of rank $0$. If $S \neq 0$ then because $R$ is a PID, we have $S = (r)$ for some $r \in R$ which is free with basis $\{ r \}$ and of rank $1$.
For the inductive step, take $S$ a submodule of $R^n$ and let $S \cap R^{n-1}$ denote the set of first $n-1$ coordinates of elements of $S$. We then have $S \cap R^{n-1} \hookrightarrow R^{n-1}$ and by induction hypothesis, $S \cap R^{n-1}$ is free of rank $\leq n-1$.
Now consider the projection homomorphism on the $n$-th coordinate, restricted to $S$, i.e $\pi_n : S \to R$. The image of $\pi_n$ is a submodule of $R$ and just like in the base case, it is free of rank $\leq 1$.
We finally have the split short exact sequence
$$ 0 \longrightarrow S \cap R^{n-1} \overset{i}{\longrightarrow} S \overset{\pi_n}{\longrightarrow} \mathrm{Image}(\pi_n) \longrightarrow 0 $$
and thus $S \cong (S \cap R^{n-1}) \oplus \mathrm{Image}(\pi_n)$. Since direct sum of free modules is free, we have that $S$ is free, and since the summands have rank $\leq n-1$ and $\leq 1$ respectively, the rank of $S$ is $\leq n$.
Questions:

Is the proof correct?
Is it correct to say the $0$ module has basis $\varnothing$ and rank
$= 0$?
By repeatedly applying the decomposition $$ S \cong (S \cap R^{n-1}) \oplus \mathrm{Image}(\pi_n), $$ would this prove $S \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \mathrm{Image}(\pi_i)$?
If I think of a line $L$ in the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e $L = \{ (x, \lambda x) : x \in \mathbb{R} \} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, then the above would give $L \cong \mathrm{Image}(\pi_1) \oplus \mathrm{Image}(\pi_2)$, but both images would be non-zero since pairs $(x, \lambda x)$ have non-zero elements in both coordinates, finally giving that $L$ has dimension $2$ which is obviously false. Is this reasoning correct? What has to happen, in the context of the proof above, for $S$ to have rank strictly less than $n$? Because just like in this example, a subspace can have dimension strictly less than the whole space, without having some null coordinate.


Your proof looks good to me, and while "no one cares about the empty case" it is formally accurate that $0$ is free with empty basis: indeed if $F:\mathsf{Set}\to\mathsf{RMod}$ is the free module functor, $F(\emptyset)=0$. The rank is zero. One way to really formalise this; $F(X)$ (a free $R$-module with basis $X$) is canonically modelled by $\{f:X\to R\,|\,\{x\in X:f(x)\neq0\}\text{ is finite }\}$ with the induced pointwise $R$-module structure; if $X=\emptyset$, then this module has only one element and is identifiable with the constant zero function - the zero element ($X$ has no elements, so all functions from $X$ are vacuously the same).
However, be careful in the next part! $S\cong\bigoplus\mathrm{im}(\pi_i)$ but the $\pi_i$ are not what you think they are. We would have to consider $\pi_n:S\to R^n\to R$, $\pi_{n-1}:S\cap R^{n-1}\to R^{n-1}\to R$, $\pi_{n-2}:S\cap R^{n-2}\to R^{n-2}\to R$... and so on. Not $\pi_{n-1}:S\to R^n\to R$ in the $(n-1)$th coordinate of $R^n$. This is just due to how the induction works; you pass to the case of $S\cap R^{n-1}$ seen as a submodule of $R^{n-1}$.
For example, in the case of a line $(\lambda\neq0)$ the $\pi_2$ is what you think it is and has image $\Bbb R$. What is $\pi_1$? $L\cap\Bbb R^{2-1}$ is $L$'s intersection with the $x$-axis... which is $\{0\}$. $\pi_1$ has to be (by the inductive process) the map $\{0\}=L\cap\Bbb R\hookrightarrow\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ which has zero image. And indeed, $L\cong 0\oplus\Bbb R$, so there are no problems.
If $S$ has rank strictly less than $n$, then either $S\cap R^k$ is going to vanish for small enough $k$ or the "$\pi_i$" (!! which must be more carefully interpreted) are going to have zero image. For example, in the case of the line we say $\pi_1$ had zero image if $\lambda\neq0$ and also that $L\cap\Bbb R=0$. If $\lambda=0$, we get the opposite effect of $L\cap\Bbb R$ being nontrivial.. but $\pi_2$ has zero image.

"$L \cap \mathbb{R}^{2-1}$ is $L$'s intersection with the $x$-axis", okay so $S \cap R^{n-1}$ is actually the set of tuples in $S$ with $n$-th coordinate equal to $0$, correct? not the "set of first n−1 coordinates of elements of $S$" as I wrote in the proof. It makes more sense this way and I think this was causing the rest of my confusion. Thank you.

@Nebzat You’re welcome. That’s right, it’s the set of tuples with $n$th coordinate zero (inside $R^n$). When you inductively view it as a submodule of $R^{n-1}$, it becomes the set of first $(n-1)$ coordinates of elements of $S$ which have zero last coordinate, if you like. The set of first $(n-1)$ coordinates of elements of $S$ is instead $f(S)$ where $f:R^n\to R^{n-1}$ projects down to the first $(n-1)$ coordinates. It is true that $S\cap R^{n-1}\subseteq f(S)$ though.
